# How to redirect user to any specific page if he type any wrong controller name in url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

Here whats the scenario ,

Whenever user want to hit url like

www.abc.com/Controller/Action
Then output is coming correct.

But incase if he type anything wrong in the url or misspell the url i want to redirect him to Error page stating that URL is not correct.

Comment: go through this link: http://www.devcurry.com/2012/06/aspnet-mvc-handling-exceptions-and-404.html

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on the custom errors in Web.config file and specify the redirect attribute. All you have to do is to find  and into this element you need to add

```
*<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPage"> </customErrors>*.
```

This will redirect every error to this specific page "/ErrorPage". If you want to catch current errors you can use this:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Account/Login">
      <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/ErrorPage" />
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/ErrorPage" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Account/Login" />
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Comment: But my error page is inside shared folder and when i try to pass that location it can't be accessible...

Comment: <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/View/Shared/Error.cshtml">
      <error statusCode="400" redirect="~/View/Shared/Error.cshtml" />
      <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/View/Shared/Error.cshtml" />
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/View/Shared/Error.cshtml" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/View/Shared/Error.cshtml" />
      <error statusCode="408" redirect="~/View/Shared/Error.cshtml" />
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/View/Shared/Error.cshtml" />
      <error statusCode="503" redirect="~/View/Shared/Error.cshtml" />
    </customErrors>

Comment: Is this working for you?

<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/View/Shared/Error.cshtml"></customErrors>

Comment: Its start working,,i just create a new error page inside my main controller and replace the shared location by current location then it start working...thanx

Comment: I am glad I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess file

ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/errors/404.php [L]

Answer (score 0):

```
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/PageYouNeed"> </customErrors>
</system.web>
```